# Foreachloop accordion where the title closes every 2 and the body closes every 2 but are contained in a single row

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to build a special accordion or collapse in this sense as it's Bootstrap, and I am having a hard time getting the code to cooperate.

I am using a `foreach` loop to display a repeater. Within it, I have the header, and the body. I am doing rows of 2 each. However, this is how I need it laid out. I need 1 row to hold the header and body, then inside that, 2 more rows. One row is for the header, and one row is for the body. This way the content is full span under the header.

**Here is a visual of what I am talking about**

[image: Here is a visual of what I am talking about]

I am not sure with my code what I am doing wrong. I've tried running a `foreach` loop twice, I've tried a modulus inside the loop to close the header row and reopen it, and the same for the body. However that just doesn't sit well at all. Every odd item opens and closes the head and that's it. The body is contained within the header.

I don't have anything live to showcase, but here is my code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion_<?php echo $accordion_widget_title; ?>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <?php $x = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach( $instance['row_repeater'] as $i => $repeater ) :

      // Concatenate the Accordion Title, then convert it to a lower case string
      $accordion_title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $repeater[ 'row_accordion_title' ] );
      $accordion_title = strtolower( $accordion_title );
      $accordion_title = $accordion_title . '_' . $x;

      // Start Accordion Title Loop ?>
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-<?php echo $accordion_title; ?>">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-<?php echo $accordion_widget_title; ?>" href="#item-<?php echo $accordion_title; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="item-<?php echo $accordion_title; ?>">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <?php _e( $repeater[ 'row_accordion_title' ], 'boss' ); ?>
          </h4>
        </a>
      </div>

    <?php if ( ( $x % 2 == 0 ) ) : ?>
      </div><div class="panel panel-default">
    <?php endif; ?>

  <?php $x++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <?php foreach( $instance['row_repeater'] as $i => $repeater ) :
      // Concatenate the Accordion Title, then convert it to a lower case string
      $accordion_title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $repeater[ 'row_accordion_title' ] );
      $accordion_title = strtolower( $accordion_title );
      $accordion_title = $accordion_title . '_' . $x;
      // Start Accordion Title Content ?>
      <div id="item-<?php echo $accordion_title; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php echo $accordion_title; ?>">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <?php _e( $repeater[ 'row_accordion_content' ], 'boss' ); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php if ( ( $x % 2 == 0 )  ) : ?>
        </div><div class="panel panel-default">
      <?php endif; ?>

    <?php $x++; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Here is another variation of what I've tried

```
<div class="panel-group<?php if ( !empty( $additional_class ) ) : echo $additional_class; endif; ?>" id="accordion_<?php echo $accordion_widget_title; ?>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <?php $x = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach( $instance['row_repeater'] as $i => $repeater ) : ?>
      <?php
        // Concatenate the Accordion Title, then convert it to a lower case string
        $accordion_title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $repeater[ 'row_accordion_title' ] );
          $accordion_title = strtolower( $accordion_title );
          $accordion_title = $accordion_title . '_' . $x;
      ?>
        <?php // Start Accordion Title Loop ?>
        <?php if ( ( $x % 2 == 1 ) || ( $x == 1 ) ) : ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <?php endif; ?>

          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-<?php echo $accordion_title; ?>">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-<?php echo $accordion_widget_title; ?>" href="#item-<?php echo $accordion_title; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="item-<?php echo $accordion_title; ?>">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <?php _e( $repeater[ 'row_accordion_title' ], 'boss' ); ?>
              </h4>
            </a>
          </div>

        <?php $x++; ?>
        <?php if ( ( $x % 2 == 1 ) || ( $x == 1 ) ) : ?>
       </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>

<div class="panel-group" data-parent="#accordion-<?php echo $accordion_widget_title; ?>" id="accordion_<?php echo $accordion_widget_title; ?>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <?php $x = 1; ?>
      <?php foreach( $instance['row_repeater'] as $i => $repeater ) : ?>

          <?php
          // Concatenate the Accordion Title, then convert it to a lower case string
          $accordion_title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $repeater[ 'row_accordion_title' ] );
          $accordion_title = strtolower( $accordion_title );
          $accordion_title = $accordion_title . '_' . $x;
          ?>
        <?php // Start Accordion Title Content ?>
        <?php if ( ( $x % 2 == 1 ) || ( $x == 1 ) ) : ?>
          <div class="panel-body-row">
        <?php endif; ?>
            <div id="item-<?php echo $accordion_title; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php echo $accordion_title; ?>">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <?php _e( $repeater[ 'row_accordion_content' ], 'boss' ); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
            <?php $x++; ?>
            <?php if ( ( $x % 2 == 1 ) || ( $x == 1 ) ) : ?>
          </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

      <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I'm just not 100% sure what it is I'm not grasping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think that the PHP function array_chunk will make your life much easier. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

I won't try to recreate all your HTML here, but here's the basic idea you could use:

```
//Split our repeaters into an array of arrays, each with 2 elements
$rows = array_chunk($instance['row_repeater'], 2);

foreach($rows as $row){
  echo "<div class='row'>";
    foreach($row as $items){
       echo "<div class='col-sm-6'>";
       echo $items('row_accordion_title');
       // echo the rest of your repeater stuff...
       echo "</div>";
    }
  echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. This did exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach to generating the HTML with PHP is making it difficult to troubleshoot. You should have the foreach loop contain the entire html output you are trying to achieve for each iteration to make it easier to keep track of. Additionally I would make sure that you are creating an incremental set of IDs for the collapsible elements to avoid confusing Boostrap's JS components. Something like:

```
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <?php
  for($i = 0; $i < count($instance['row_repeater']); $i++){
    $accordion_title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $instance['row_repeater'][$i][ 'row_accordion_title' ] );
    $accordion_title = strtolower( $accordion_title );
    $accordion_title = $accordion_title . '_' . $x;

    $out = "<div class=\"panel panel-default\">
     <div class=\"panel-heading\" role=\"tab\" id=\"heading".$i+1."\">
       <h4 class=\"panel-title\">
         <a role=\"button\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" data-parent=\"#accordion\" href=\"#collapse".$i+1."\" aria-expanded=\"true\" aria-controls=\"collapse".$i+1."\">
           ".$accordion_title."
         </a>
       </h4>
     </div>
     <div id=\"collapse".$i+1."\" class=\"panel-collapse collapse in\" role=\"tabpanel\" aria-labelledby=\"heading".$i+1."\">
        <div class=\"panel-body\">
          ".$instance['row_repeater'][$i][ 'row_accordion_content' ]."
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>";
    echo $out;
   }
   ?>
   </div>
```

Doing this will help to simplify your looping and make it easier to track down issues in your code. Additionally using the iteration of $i in the for look you can make sure you create unique IDs to prevent the bootstrap triggers from stepping on each other. Hope this helps